# style the new row on datagrid (CanUserAddRows)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can I change the new row style (of CanUserAddRows) I want the user to notice to the new row.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but I think it should work. You can try adding some `Style` for the `DataGridRow`. Add some Trigger listening to `IsNewItem`. Then you can change almost everything related to the matched `DataGridRow` via the Trigger Setter. The following code will try highlighting the new row by setting a red border around it:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="someSource">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <!-- remaining code ... -->
</DataGrid>
```